# How do you work with the Photo Library in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: picture-library

SharePoint 2010 Photo Libraries are one of the most broken features I have found yet.

It is bad enough that Microsoft Office Picture Manager 2010 MUST be installed, AND specific browser plugins from the DLL's MUST be enabled, AND the browser compatibility mode MUST be set to version 7 when 8 is the default in IE11!

Not only all that, but even afterward, once the "Download" options and "Open with Explorer" become available, they DON'T WORK!

I can't even download existing photos in the library using SharePoint Designer. How on earth am I supposed to get them back out, or expect an end user to make any sense of this?

I would have been happy enough to have a thumbnail column in a standard document library, but even that would require serious overhaul and the recreation of planet Earth.

Please help!

Already referenced and followed:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f203136a-af37-4450-838e-3787e16c91ea/problem-with-missing-menu-options-in-picture-library-office-2013?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 0):

After much searching without a satisfactory answer, I decided to make my own.
In short, it was much less than I anticipated, as in 2007, you needed to convert the list/library to XSLT first, but in 2010 it is already XSLT. I simply started with a content type of Picture and removed Doc. The columns for the Picture contenttype are rather irrelevant as they will not work as hoped, so I created a new Thumbnail column. In SharePoint designer, I drug the URL info column to the Thumbnail column and then wrapped the value in an  tag, and used javascript to open a new window as the target attribute is no longer valid per doctype.
I then set two XSL:if's. One is to check if the content type (column must be in view...unless maybe this could be instantiated without adding the column to the view) is a folder, and then renders a folder graphic which I uploaded for the thumbnail, and the other checks if it is not a folder, and then renders the image url. Otherwise, any folders you create would not have a thumbnail obviously. Don't forget to scale the thumbnail image size to something appropriate.